# Find Items Where All Parts Are In Stock

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, relational-division

Hopefully fairly easy query, but my mind is just not working this afternoon. I've got the following tables:

```
tblCocktail
CockTailID  CocktailName
1           Alexander

tblCocktailIngredient
CocktailID  IngredientID   Amount   UnitID
1           1              3        1
1           2              3        1
1           3              3        1

tblIngredient
IngredientID  IngredientName   OnHandAmount   OnHandUnitID
1             Cognac           .75            2
2             Creme de Cacao   .9             2
3             Cream            .5             2

tblUnitConversion
FromUnitID    ToUnitID   Factor 
1             2          100
```

What I'm trying to do is find a list of cocktails I can make since I have enough on hand of all of the ingredients. I have the following query:

```
SELECT tblCocktail.CocktailName
FROM tblCocktail INNER JOIN (tblIngredient INNER JOIN (tblCocktailIngredient INNER JOIN  tblUnitConversion ON tblCocktailIngredient.UnitID = tblUnitConversion.ToUnitID) ON (tblIngredient.IngredientID = tblCocktailIngredient.IngredientID) AND (tblIngredient.OnHandUnit = tblUnitConversion.FromUnitID)) ON tblCocktail.CocktailID = tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID
WHERE ((([tblCocktailIngredient].[Amount]*[Factor])<[tblIngredient].[OnHandAmount]));
```

This will give a list of all Cocktails and related ingredients where the onHand is greater than the Amount, however, I only want to list Cocktails where ALL of the ingredients have enough quantity on hand.

Comment: Hos is the tblUnitConversion related to the other tables?  Are you trying to specify that an Amount from a  row in tblCocktailIngredient amount must be multiplied by 100 in order to be comparable to a row from "tblIngredient"?

Comment: Actually, an OnHandAmount from a row from tblIngredient must be multiplied by 100 in order to compare to the "Amount" field on tblCocktailIngredient.

Comment: You need to say "Where NO ingredient has LESS than the required amount on hand", i.e. `NOT EXISTS` or similar.

Comment: The concept is *universal quantification*, the relational operator is called *division*, popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). Click on the `relational-division` tag to find Q&A with relevant examples and links to helpful documents such as [On Making Relational Division Comprehensible](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/research/divpresentation.pdf) and [Divided We Stand](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tblCocktail.CocktailName
FROM tblCocktail
WHERE   (   SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    tblCocktailIngredient 
            WHERE tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID = tblCocktail.CockTailID) 
        =
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    tblIngredient 
                    INNER JOIN (tblCocktailIngredient
                                INNER JOIN tblUnitConversion 
                                    ON tblCocktailIngredient.UnitID = tblUnitConversion.FromUnitID)
                        ON (tblIngredient.IngredientID = tblCocktailIngredient.IngredientID)
                            AND (tblIngredient.OnHandUnitId = tblUnitConversion.ToUnitID) 


            WHERE   [tblCocktailIngredient].[Amount] <= [tblIngredient].[OnHandAmount]*[Factor]
                    AND tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID = tblCocktail.CocktailID )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy query, because Access requires you to be very explicit about complex outer joins.

```
SELECT tblCocktail.CocktailID, tblCocktail.CocktailName, sum(IIf(isnull(onhand.IngredientID),1,0)) AS missingIngredients
FROM (tblCocktail INNER JOIN tblCocktailIngredient ON tblCocktail.CocktailID=tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tblIngredient.IngredientID, tblIngredient.OnHandAmount*tblUnitConversion.Factor AS OnHandAmount, tblUnitConversion.FromUnitID AS OnHandUnitID
    FROM tblIngredient INNER JOIN tblUnitConversion ON tblUnitConversion.ToUnitID=tblIngredient.OnHandUnitID
)  AS onhand
ON (tblCocktailIngredient.IngredientID=onhand.IngredientID) AND (tblCocktailIngredient.UnitID=onhand.OnHandUnitID) AND (tblCocktailIngredient.Amount<=onhand.OnHandAmount)
GROUP BY tblCocktail.CocktailID, tblCocktail.CocktailName
HAVING sum(IIf(isnull(onhand.IngredientID),1,0))=0
```

(edit: realized I only needed one subquery)

To elaborate, I used the outer join to identify whether ingredients are on hand in sufficient quantity for a cocktail.  From that, grouping by cocktail lets me count the number of missing / not missing ingredients in the HAVING clause.

Note that the 'onhand' subquery might be useful to create as a named Query, to make it easy to see what you have on hand in a given unit.

Comment: After refining the query, I've realized that despite my crabbing about Access this is how I'd do this query in other databases as well, apart from the `IIf(isnull())` Access dialect.  My initial approach had an ambiguous outer join that Access refused, but I realize now it would have given an incorrect result.

Comment: Changing the `0` on the right hand side of the `HAVING` clause to a `1` or `2` would also let you answer "What could I make if I had one or 2 more ingredients?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
select result1.CocktailName
from (
    select tblCocktail.CocktailName, count(*) as NumIngredientsPerCocktail
    from tblCocktail
    inner join tblCocktailIngredient
       on tblCocktail.CocktailID = tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID
    group by tblCocktail.CocktailName
) as result1
inner join (
    select tblCocktail.CocktailName, count(*) as NumberAvailableIngredientsForCocktail
    from tblCocktail 
    inner join tblCocktailIngredient
       on tblCocktail.CocktailID = tblCocktailIngredient.CocktailID
    inner join tblIngredient
       on tblCocktailIngredient.IngredientID = tblIngredient.IngredientID
    inner join tblUnitConversion
       on tblUnitConversion.FromUnitID = tblCocktailIngredient.UnitID
      and tblUnitConversion.ToUnitID = tblIngredient.OnHandUnitID
    where tblIngredient.OnHandAmount * tblUnitConversion.Factor >= tblCocktailIngredient.Amount
    group by tblCocktail.CocktailName
) as result2
on result1.NumIngredientsPerCocktail = result2.NumberAvailableIngredientsForCocktail
and result1.CocktailName = result2.CocktailName
```

Comment: That won't run in MS Access, there are not enough parentheses.

Comment: It appears that the parentheses are matched.  Access must be complaining about something else?  This SQL will work in SQL Server.

Comment: Since Access won't re-order joins (see my complaining in my answer), it requires you to put parentheses around every pair of joins but the last.